# Simple derivative of current confusion

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

Say you have some $\textbf{B}$ field from an alternating current, $\textbf B(t) = \textbf{B}_0\cos{\omega \,t}$. And using Faraday law, e.m.f. $\varepsilon$ = turns of a coil $\times$ the time derivative of the flux of the $\textbf{B}$ field going through the coil area. $$\varepsilon = -N \cdot \frac{d\phi_B}{dt}.$$

If my $\textbf B(t)$ max has a amplitude of $0.0005$ T and a frequency of $500,000$ kHz, then does the derivative of $B(t)$ have a $1000000\pi$ constant pop out front? This seems wrong, like you can make the $\varepsilon$ voltage really high just from the frequency?

I feel like I'm missing something simple, Thank you.

Comment: In the future, please format the math in your question in Latex.

Answer (score 1):

We have the proof mathematically. It is clear that increasing the frequency increases the current induced.

However if we try analysing in the physical sense, we see that a magnetic field that varies with a large frequency oscillates faster than a one with smaller frequency. The principle of electromagnetic induction states that to generate current we should have a varying magnetic field, and not so much about how large the field is.

So yes, we can make the current very large by increasing the frequency.

Comment: Ok seems interesting if you had a loop of wire and drove a giga hertz signal through it, then the B filed would oscillate in the giga hertz range. If you put another coil near the B filed, the voltage in the second loop would have some giga hertz coefficient out front?

Comment: @ChrisBolig Yes. Frequency is the game changer in electromagnetic induction.

Answer (score 0):

Related point of interest:  The low voltage DC power supplies in many modern devices (like DVD players) rectify the incoming AC, and use that (high voltage) DC to power a high frequency oscillator.  The high frequency drives a small step down transformer (with a high self inductance) and that output is rectified to give the low voltage output. This greatly reduces the size and weight of the transformer and the filter capacitors.